# Strange functional equation: $f(z)=\frac{1}{24} - \frac{1}{2z} + \frac{\pi^2}{z^2} \left( \frac{1}{6} -4 \ f \left(\frac{-4\pi^2}{z}\right)\right)$

Tags: analysis, functional-equations

I would like to get some information about the following functional equation:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{24} - \frac{1}{2z}  + \frac{\pi^2}{z^2} \left ( \frac{1}{6} -4 \ f \left (\frac{-4\pi^2}{z}\right )\right )$$

This functional relationship must hold only for $\mathfrak{R}(z)>0$. I would like to know wether it is possible to know what types of functions hold it.

To be clear, I do not know where to start from. I have barely worked with functional equations in my life.

Any help or bibliography will be welcomed.

**Edit:**
Answering the comments, we are supposed to know that $f(z)$ as $z \to 0^+$ is $ O\left ( \frac{1}{z^2} \right )$. Moreover, we know that $f(-2\pi)=f(2\pi)=\frac{1}{24} - \frac{1}{8\pi}$. Thank you for the help received.

**Edit 2:**
$f(z)$ is even: $f(z)=f(-z)$. From here, we could get the follwing functional equation for $\mathfrak{R}(z)<0$:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{24} + \frac{1}{2z}  + \frac{\pi^2}{z^2} \left ( \frac{1}{6} -4 \ f \left (\frac{4\pi^2}{z}\right )\right )$$

So that we can remove the $-$ sign from the first equation to get for $\mathfrak{R}(z)>0$:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{24} - \frac{1}{2z}  + \frac{\pi^2}{z^2} \left ( \frac{1}{6} -4 \ f \left (\frac{4\pi^2}{z}\right )\right )$$

Comment: It might help to multiply through by $z$ and define $g(z)=zf(z)$  Do you know anything about the behavior as $z \to 0?$

Comment: @Ross Well, we know that for $\mathfrak{R}(z)=0$ the functional relationship does not hold. However, as $z \to 0^+$ the function diverges (I need to study how fast it does)

Comment: $\pi e^{-iz/2} f(e^{iz})$ (or something like that) is an even function plus a simple term, that's all what your functional equation says.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That formula puts no restrictions at all on your function on the half-plane $\Re(z) > 0$.

If you know $f(z_1)$ for some $z_1$ with $\Re(z_1) > 0$, then it tells you the value of $f(z_2)$ where $z_2 = \frac{-4\pi^2}{z_1}$. But $\Re(z_2) < 0$. And if you try to use the formula again, the new value is for $\frac{-4\pi^2}{z_2} = z_1$ (where it gives the same value for $f(z_1)$ that you started with).

So, you can choose *any* function $g$ on $\Re(z) > 0$, then define $$f(z) = \begin{cases} g(z) & \Re(z) > 0\\\frac{1}{24} - \frac{1}{2z}  + \frac{\pi^2}{z^2} \left ( \frac{1}{6} -4 \ g \left(\frac{-4\pi^2}{z}\right )\right) & \Re(z) < 0\end{cases}$$
$f$ will be defined everywhere except the imaginary line and will satisfy your equation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! And what about $f$ being not a piecewise-defined function? If that were possible, what information would we have about it?

Comment: "Piecewise-defined" is a not a class of functions. It is one way of expressing a function, but doesn't say anything in particular about the nature of the function itself. *Every* function satisfying your equation and defined everywhere but the imaginary axis will fit my description. (The functions can also be defined on the imaginary axis, except at 0 - I just didn't bother with those details, since you seem to be avoiding it in your post.)

Comment: That's true, I do not bother about the imaginary axis. However, I expected the result to be a smooth function with a closed form -I shouldn't have used the term "piecewise".

Comment: That is the point. Infinitely many nice smooth functions obey your equation. An even bigger infinity of nasty completely discontinous functions also obey your equation. The *only* thing your equation does is force behavior in $\Re z < 0$ to match whatever behavior is found for for $\Re z > 0$. It is no more restrictive than the condition of being odd or even.